# Cannot open shopping cart dialog - Material Dialog - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a shopping app, of which I can open a material dialog with product details and from there add to cart.

When I try to open my cart dialog however, I cannot seem to get anything open...

I'm unsure whether it is because my routing of data is incorrect, or whether the actual opening of the dialog is wrong. But seeing as one of my dialogs works... I'm stumped.

[image]

**cart-button.ts**

```
export class CartButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  products: any[];
  numProducts: number;
  cartTotal: number;

  constructor(private cartService: CartService, public dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.products = [];
    this.numProducts = 0;
    this.cartTotal = 0;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cartService.productAdded$.subscribe(data => {
      this.products = data.products;
      this.cartTotal = data.cartTotal;
      this.numProducts = data.products.reduce((acc, prod) => {
        acc += prod.quantity;
        return acc;
      }, 0);
    });
  }

  openCartDialog(prods) {
    console.log(prods);
    this.dialog.open(CartPageComponent, {
      autoFocus: true,
      width: '600px',
      data: prods
    });
  }

}
```

**cart-page.ts**

```
export class CartPageComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() products: any[];

  constructor(
    private cartService: CartService,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any) {
    this.products = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  deleteProduct(product: Product) {
    this.cartService.deleteFromCart(product);
  }
}
```

**app.module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomepageComponent,
    ProductThumbnailComponent,
    ProductPageComponent,
    CartPageComponent,
    ToolbarComponent,
    NavComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    CartButtonComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule,
    LayoutModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [ProductPageComponent, CartPageComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

FYI: All Material modules are imported via `MaterialModule`

**[STACKBLITZ](https://shopping-app.stackblitz.io)**

Comment: I have added a new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark `MD_DIALOG_DATA` optional,

```
@Optional() @Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any).
```

If problem exists, in your module add `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` to providers,

```
providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
```

Comment: Aha! Wonderful! Thanks for the advice. It was the `@Optional()` that saved me here.

Comment: so shall I edit te answer and remove the providers thing?

Comment: You can leave it in. You never know, it may help out in future :P